# Getting an error when creating a variable that is an array of a custom class

Tags: swift, class

I have a custom class called Message.

```
import UIKit

class Message {
    var sender: String
    var message: String

    init?(sender: String, message: String) {

        self.sender = sender
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

I also have a custom class called Chat that has a variable, called messageList, that is an array of the Message class.

```
class Chat {

    //MARK: Properties
    var name: String
    var image: UIImage?
    var animal: String
    var messageList = [Message]()

    //MARK: Initialisation
    init?(name: String, image: UIImage?, animal: String) {

        if name.isEmpty || animal.isEmpty {
            return nil
         }

        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.animal = animal
        let firstMessage = Message(sender: "animal", message: "Hi! Nice meeting you!")
        self.messageList.append(firstMessage)
    }

}
```

I have tried many different ways, but each time, I get an error when messageList is declared saying the following: "Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C" or "Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type".

Thank you in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are declared as internal by default, so you have to add the public keyword to make them public.

```
import UIKit

public class Message {
    var sender: String
    var message: String

    init?(sender: String, message: String) {

        self.sender = sender
        self.message = message
    }
}
```